# Swift didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo can't get value

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I use push notification, and have this func:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if let msg = userInfo["msg"] as? NSObject {
        println(msg)
    }
    GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
        userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

this prints me:

```
{"model":"que","data":{"id":101,"vehicle":{"license_plate":"test","taxi":{"id":1,"logo":"/media/logos/mega_CxRn739.png.75x75_q85_crop.png","name":"Mega","city":"Novi Pazar","country":"Srbija"},"label":"A01"}}}

// prettify:
{
    "model": "que",
    "data": {
        "id": 101,
        "vehicle": {
            "license_plate": "test",
            "taxi": {
                "id": 1,
                "logo": "/media/logos/mega_CxRn739.png.75x75_q85_crop.png",
                "name": "Mega",
                "city": "Novi Pazar",
                "country": "Srbija"
            },
            "label": "A01"
        }
    }
}
```

Now when i use:

```
if let msg = userInfo["msg"] as? NSObject {
    println(msg["model"])
    println(msg["data"])
}
```

i can't build:

```
'NSObject' does not have a member named 'subscript'
```

How can i get this to work? I need to get all propertise after this, but can't do first step.

Image:
[image]

**FIX**:

```
if let msg = userInfo["msg"] as? String {
    if let data = msg.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        if let jsonObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(), error: nil) {
            var data = JSON(jsonObject!)
            println(data["data"])
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone have suggestion on this fix, tell me.. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm… perhaps cast `msg` as an `NSDictionary` and use `valueForKey:` to get the contents out?

Comment: Nothing happens, still same :(

Comment: Nothing at all comes out into the console? Not even a timestamp? Try `println("This should work: \(msg.whatever())")`? Are you sure the code is even executing?

Comment: Yes, i get message when print `userInfo`, and it is json..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Could you update your question with the actual output of printing both `msg` as well as its contents, in the same code block?

Comment: I uploaded image.. can you check now?

Comment: Ah nooooo, you did it wrong. The ------- is supposed to be inside the conditional code block. We need to know if the conditional downcast fails. You can figure that out using breakpoints too. If it is indeed failing, find out what class `msg` actually is. Might just be a string, in which case you'd have to parse it to create a dictionary you could use in your code.

Comment: Updated image.. like you said, it fails in second term.. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if let msg = userInfo["msg"] as? String {
    if let data = msg.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        if let jsonObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(), error: nil) {
            var data = JSON(jsonObject!)
            println(data["data"])
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone have suggestion on this fix, tell me.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the relevant objects in the payload are dictionaries, so cast the value of `msg` to something more specific

```
if let msg = userInfo["msg"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    println(msg["model"])
    println(msg["data"])
}
```

**Edit:**

It could be that the object of `msg` is just a JSON string.
Try this:

```
if let msg = userInfo["msg"] as? String {
   println("yeah, it's a string")
   if let data = msg.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
      if let jsonObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(), error: nil) {
        println(jsonObject["model"])
        println(jsonObject["data"])
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Now i don't get error, but nothing is printed. Why?

Comment: strange, casting to [String:AnyObject] works in one of my projects using APNS. Try to cast explicit `as!` instead of  `as?`, then the compiler error message might tell you what type is expected

Comment: It change to `as?`: `Forced downcast in conditional binding produces non-optional type '[String : AnyObject]'; use 'as?' to perform a conditional downcast`, btw this is `GoogleCloudMessages`, if that make any change..

Comment: Next try `as?` and `NSDictionary` as type (no brackets) and insert a `println("I'm here")` line in the block to see if the test is passed at all

Comment: Same :( i don't know why :/

Comment: I didn't notice that's about `GoogleCloudMessages`, maybe it uses a custom class, but it must be a kind of Dictionary because of the key subscripting `["msg"]`

Comment: Hi @vadian , i got stuck one of issue in ios11 device push notification , where when i got notiifcation in form of [Anyhasable:any] , can't convert into dictionary , help me in this , here is my question link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53776835/3400991