# How to get userInfo JSON Value inside didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)

        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active
        {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)

            if let msg = userInfo["test"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
            {
                print(msg)
            }
        }
```

my userInfo["test"] JSON value is :

```
> Printing description of userInfo:
▿ 3 elements
  ▿ [0] : 2 elements
    - .0 : message
    - .1 : 1235
  ▿ [1] : 2 elements
    - .0 : aps
    - .1 : 0 elements
  ▿ [2] : 2 elements
    - .0 : link
    - .1 :
```

I can get my userInfo data, but i don't know why my msg value nothing ( not even nil just nothing to show)
How can i go till print(msg) ?

**UPDATED**

Here is what my push like :

> $this->parsepush->send( array( "channels" => ['test'], "data" => > $post_data ));

inside $post_data example :

> $post_data = 
>   json_encode(array
>   ('link' => $link, 'message' => $message));\

I've tried instruction from, yet i can't do a simple print too.

[get Value from userInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223835/swift-didreceiveremotenotification-userinfo-cant-get-value)

**EDIT**

Still skipped the "aps" part.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bkQK.png)

**My JSON**

Here is my `Json` looks like :

```
> {  
  "aps":{  
     "alert":{  
        "title":"$title",
        "body":"$message"
     },
     "badge":"1"
  },
  "adira":{  
     "link":"$link"
  }
}
```

And this is my Code :

```
>   func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
              //  PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
       // PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        if let msg = userInfo["message"] as? String {
            print(msg)
            print("a")
        }     
        if let alertDict = userInfo["aps"]?["alert"] as? Dictionary<String, String> {
            print("title : ", alertDict["title"])
            print("body :", alertDict["body"]!)
            print("badge: ", alertDict["badge"]!)
            print("b")
        }      
        if let link = userInfo["link"] as? String {
            print(link)
            print("c")
        }
    }
}
```

But still i can't get my `aps` data. still nil or nothing.

If you want a specific code, just click link below :

[Full code AppDelegate.swift](http://codepad.org/RxrGQ9dV)

**EDIT 2**

i use print(userInfo) directly and the printout is :

> Object has been saved. 
>   [message: iOS push, aps: { }, link: ]

**Update 2**

I tried to push from parse.com, not my website (3rd party). 
and this is what i get from normal print(userInfo)

```
> [aps: {
    alert = 12345abc;
    sound = default;
}]
```

So i guess i'll just changed and add something inside to my JSON From my Website to :

```
[aps:{
   alert = $message;
   sound = default;
   link = $link;
}]
```

Something like that ?

Comment: Well, there's no value with a `test` key, only `message`, `aps` and `link`. Please include what you send.

Comment: @jcaron  
here what i push from website 
`$this->parsepush->send(array(
            "channels" => ['test'],
            "data" => $post_data
        ));`
So can i convert JSON to Dictionary ? or String?

Comment: Don't add code in comments, edit your question to add the code. Also, you actually did not include what you send (`$post_data`). The JSON is already decoded by iOS when you receive it, but you haven't told us what the JSON you send is.

Comment: Ok sorry, gonna fix it. @jcaron

Comment: here's the update, that function is to listen a push notification from my webservice using parse.com . my web service uses JSON format to push it's data, using 2 element : ( "message" & "link" ), link is nullable. the userInfo already correctly accept the data as printed, now i need to extract the message data (ex:"1235" just like above data) so i can use it to create a notificaiton with a title of that data ("1235") i have updated too my push @jcaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no key `test` in the APNS payload.
If the value for key `message` is guaranteed to be sent always you can easily unwrap the value

```
let msg = userInfo["message"] as! String
print(msg)
```

otherwise use optional binding

```
if let msg = userInfo["message"] as? String {
    print(msg)
}
```

To get the `alert` dictionary from the `aps` key and print for example the `body` string use

```
if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String:Any],
   let alertDict = aps["alert"] as? [String:String] {
    print("body :", alertDict["body"]!)
}
```

Comment: yes thank you so much this works, however i tried the same with 'aps' it doesn't work, just skip away
But it works for "message" and "link". any idea? @vadian

Comment: still skipped that aps part. I've upload the pic @vadian

Comment: Your JSON value dump says that the `aps` key contains `0 elements` aka an empty dictionary.

Comment: what if my `aps` declare like this

 `{"aps":{"alert":"Testmessage","badge":"1"}}` 

is it right or wrong? @vadian

Comment: `alert` must be a dictionary with specific keys: {"aps":{"alert":{"title":"TestTitle,"body":"Testmessage"},"badge":"1"}}. Please read the documentation how to create the payload https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1

Comment: this help me so much, thanks for your help ! @vadian . appreciate it !

Comment: oh i have one more question, do i have design `aps` code inside JSON or i can do inside my didReceiveRemoteNotification ? @vadian

Comment: You have to create the `aps` code on the server which sends the remote notification

Comment: hey i have update some problem, i tried as you say but still error. @vadian

Comment: Please read your dictionary carefully: There is no key `message` anymore and the key `link` has a parent dictionary with key `adira`. Print `userInfo` directly after `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called (with the Swift print command, not the other one you used before) and add the result to your question.

Comment: hey i have print userInfo directly above @vadian

Comment: I don't mean the JSON string nor the odd `Printing description` showing the number of elements but the Swift representation with square brackets using `print(userInfo)` displayed in the console when the remote notification has been received.

Comment: did you mean like this one ? sorry I'm confused.

` 3 elements
  ▿ [0] : 2 elements
    - .0 : message
    - .1 : 1235` 

Question : Can i just create my own notification without using `aps` ? @vadian

Comment: No, I mean the result in the console of a simple `print` statement, not in the debugger. By the way, the `Printing description of userInfo` is not the actual one, it doesn't match the JSON.

Comment: console only show this :  `[message: iOS push, aps: { }, link: ]` i can do a ss tomorrow.
yeah i think my json doesnt match too, kinda weird.
By the way, can i just custom my notification without uisng `aps` ? if yes thats better. @vadian

Comment: There you can see why the `aps` value doesn't display anything: It's empty. As far as I know the APNS payload requires at least the `aps` dictionary to be able to inform the user properly.

Comment: hey i have fond something, please look at it. thanks @vadian

Answer (score 1):

I use APNs Provider and json payload as below

```
{
  "aps" : {
    "alert" : {
      "title" : "I am title",
      "body" : "message body."
    },
  "sound" : "default",
  "badge" : 1
  }
}
```

Due to the provider originates it as a JSON-defined dictionary that iOS converts to an `NSDictionary` object, without subscript like `Dictionary`, but can use `value(forKey:)`

Reference from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application)

This's my way for Swift 4

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    guard application.applicationState == .active else { return }
    guard let alertDict = ((userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary)?.value(forKey: "alert")) as? NSDictionary,
        let title = alertDict["title"] as? String,
        let body = alertDict["body"] as? String
        else { return }
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: body, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAct = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(okAct)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
}
```